# css/sass :not(:first-of-type) not working, is hiding all elements of type

Tags: css, sass

I have a sass block that i have tried several different ways:

I've tried this:

```
.progress-body {
    display: none;
    &:first-of-type {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

and this:

```
.progress-body {
    &:not(:first-of-type) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

and this:

```
.progress-body:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}
```

when applied to HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body progress-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p class="lead">Step 1: Choose your template...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body progress-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p class="lead">Step 2: Compose your email...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the result is that it hides all the elements with the `progress-body` class. This is normally  pretty straight forward CSS so no idea what is wrong here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `progress-body` is not the `first-of-type`, this would *technically* be `.panel-heading` since the `first-of-type` refers to the *type* element selector (`div`) and *not the class*.

> The `:first-of-type` CSS [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) represents the first element of
>   its type among a group of sibling elements.

Ref: [`:first-of-type` - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)

Consider wrapping your `.progress-body` elements in a containing element, you will achieve the expected behaviour, since `.progress-body` would be *the first of its type* **with** the class name `.progress-body`.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.progress-body:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  </div>
  <div class="panel-outer-body">
    <div class="panel-body progress-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="lead">Step 1: Choose your template...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body progress-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="lead">Step 2: Compose your email...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yea ok this makes sense now!

Answer (score 2):

If you can't wrap as UncaughtTypeError wrote in his answer, youcan use (general) sibling selectors.

```
.progress-body + .progress-body {display: none;}
```

or

```
.progress-body ~ .progress-body {display: none;}
```

I expect the first is block by default, if you didn't change it elsewhere.